# How to make multiselect work in sails.js using built in vue and ajax forms?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, sails.js, multi-select

Im trying to using a simple multiselect form with standard sails.js 1.0 using ajax / vue.  Everything seems right according to Vue.js site, but I'm getting errors:

On screen errors:
Error: In directive model inserted hook:  expects an Array value for its binding, but got Undefined.

This is a simplified version, throws same errors as a select with all the ajax properties filled in.

```
<select v-model="formData.select" multiple>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
```

The above will work without the v-model="" included OR without the 'multiple' included, but how could I make this work as-is in Sails.js?

Comment: Could you please show the vue model structure as well? it seems `formData.select` is not defined correctly

Comment: Hi Firman, Problem also persists if I use just `formData` with no `.select`.  This is built on sails.js and if I simply remove 'multiple' from the select tag it will work perfectly.  Error happens when I add the 'multiple' and turn it into a multi-select.  Could be an issue with parasails supporting it? -Mike

Comment: I should clarify, sails.js uses parasails which is built on top of Vue

Answer (score 0):

In sails, seems the 'formData' field autogenerates using an array for form fields, so I just hardcoded in the v-model="formData.select" to below and seems to eliminate the error.

xxx.page.js file:

```
data: {
formData: { /* … */
            'select': [],
        },
```